# How do I use pywin32 to extract data from task usage in msproject?

Tags: python, vba, pywin32, ms-project

I am trying to use pywin32 Python Library to extract data from MSProject .mpp file to an excel file where I want my employees to register their work hour.

I can extract data from any field I want except the Task Usage Table where it shows for every day how many hours an assignment (a person X a task) has to be done (Work) and has been done (Actual Work) and allows users to fill out the number of hours.

[Image of the Task Usage Table](https://i.ibb.co/9cr50M4/Capture123456445.jpg)

It seems that there is an Object for it if the case is VBA Programming, called [TimeScaleValue object (Project) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.timescalevalue)

While it seems there is no similar attribute under Task object in pywin32.
Are there any pieces of advice? Thanks a lot!

```py
import win32com
...
Tasks_collection=ActiveProject.Tasks
for t in Tasks_collection:
   for r in t.Assignments:
        TSV_collection = r.TimeScaleValue('06/01/2019','08/01/2019')
...
```

Command Line gave me a message: AttributeError: win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Project . Object Library.Assignment instance object has no attribute 'TimeScaleValue'

Are there any pieces of advice? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It says to use `TimeScaleValues (index)`, where index is the index number of the timescaled data item, to return a single `TimeScaleValue` object. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.timescalevalues

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice it and finally reached the solution for it. I'll paste it down below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I dealt with it. For everyone who needs the solution.

```py
Tasks_collection=ActiveProject.Tasks
for t in Tasks_collection:
  for r in t.Assignments:
    #get a TimeScaleValues Collection
    TSV_collection=r.TimeScaleData('06/01/2019','08/01/2019',\
          pjAssignmentTimescaledWork,pjTimescaleDays)
    for tsv in TSV_collection:
      print(tsv.Value)
```

[Assignment.TimeScaleData method (Project) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.assignment.timescaledata)

[TimeScaleValues object (Project) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.timescalevalues)

[TimeScaleValue object (Project) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.timescalevalue)

Comment: Consider marking your answer as accepted so that this question no longer shows in the unanswered queue.

Comment: Where do the variables pjAssignmentTimescaledWork and pjTimescaleDays come from?