# How to access Enumerations of MS Project in Python through pywin32?

Tags: python, vba, pywin32, ms-project

I'm using `win32com` to access MS Project data from Python. Now I need to access the `TimeScaleData` of an assignment using code similar to the one shown in the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56884178/how-do-i-use-pywin32-to-extract-data-from-task-usage-in-msproject).

```
Tasks_collection = ActiveProject.Tasks
for t in Tasks_collection:
    for r in t.Assignments:
        TSV_collection = r.TimeScaleData('06/01/2019','08/01/2019',\
                                         pjAssignmentTimescaledWork,pjTimescaleDays)
        for tsv in TSV_collection:
            print(tsv.Value)
```

But I have no idea where or how `pjAssignmentTimescaledWork` and `pjTimescaleDays` are defined. I've already checked multiple questions regarding VBA, MS Project, `win32com` in Python, but none of them explain how to access the enumerations of the project model. I found out what `pjAssignmentTimescaledWork` actually was when I came across [Microsoft's VBA documentation for Enumerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project(enumerations)). But I haven't been able to find how to access those variables from Python, using `win32com`.

I also checked Microsoft Office's constants, generating them myself following the code I found [here](https://ericgarlicblog.wordpress.com/2018/03/24/how-to-generate-ms-office-constants/), but none of those constants are the ones shown in Microsoft's documentation.

Can someone offer me some insight regarding MS Project Enumerations in Python? Or more specifically, how to define `pjAssignmentTimescaledWork` and `pjTimescaleDays`, so that I can use the method `TimeScaleData` with its `Type` and `TimeScaleUnit` parameters (documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.resource.timescaledata))?

Comment: Take a look at [Accessing enumeration constants in Excel COM using Python and win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465810/accessing-enumeration-constants-in-excel-com-using-python-and-win32com) and [How do I import a COM object namespace/enumeration in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646230/how-do-i-import-a-com-object-namespace-enumeration-in-python).

Comment: I already ran `makepy` using those steps and generated a file called `MSO.py`, but none of the constants listed there match any variable name in Microsoft's documentation about enumerations. I'm either missing something or Microsoft Office `constants` are not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can always declare just the specific constants you need...